# Blinking tiled map Java Libgdx - rendering tiled maps

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, tiles

I have 3 tiles and i am trying to render them for a tile map. My Code So Far: public void

```
render(float delta) {

Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
game.batch.begin();
int w;
w = 120;

int h;
h = 1080/16;

int tileX = 0;
int tileY = 0;
Texture currentTile = null;
for(int i=0; i<w; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<h; j++){

        switch(MathUtils.random(2)){

        case 0:
            currentTile = grass;
            tiles.add(grass);
            break;
        case 1:
            currentTile = stone;
            break;
        case 2:
            currentTile = dirt;
            break;
            }
        game.batch.draw(currentTile, i*120, j*120);

    }
    }
```

The problem is hat it renders fine apart from the tiles keep blinking - as they are constantly being rerendered i think. But how can i stop this is the only way to use a 2d array, if so pls show how to:

**Render the array**, in this format what would i put instead of currentTile?:

```
game.batch.draw(currentTile, i*120, j*120);
```

**Setting up the array**, what should it look like, this?:

```
Texture[] tiles = new Texture[1];
```

**How to add tiles to and construct the array properly**, any other detail would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a blinking screen occurs when areas of your canvas have nothing drawn to them. Before you start trying to draw the tiles, create/fill with some color (black, blue, whatever) that fills the screen. From here draw your BG items, tiles, player/entities, etc.

Comment: It still blinks, its not because they are constantly being rerendered?

Comment: Typically when making a game, everything is draw each time your game updates (30, 60, whatever) times a second. If you did not continuously update the screen/redraw the images, nothing would ever move.

You may find this or other tutorials helpful:
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Tutorial-series.aspx

Comment: Also before you draw your tiles, you should do something like this:



`Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

Comment: I just added in the Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

Answer (score 0):

At each gameloop you are setting a new Random texture to the tile, this means that in 1 second a tile can change up to 60 times(fps) per second

To fix this, it depense whether the tiles should be able to change or not.

-if not, predefine them in the constructor

-if they can change, set a timed event and/or action to trigger it

Comment: That is useful, they are not meant to change once they are first loaded, can you please give an example of predefining them?

Comment: Could you provide some more code?(mainly the class/folder structure, if you have any) So I can make an example suitable for your situation.

Comment: Surre what are you interested in?

Comment: I would like to see the full class where you draw your titles, not only the render() mathod.

Comment: This is the only other piece of code i have for drawing the tiles:Texture grass = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("grass.png"));
 Texture stone = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("stone.png"));
 Texture dirt = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("dirt.png"));

Comment: they are just variables, and as u can c most of my tile code is int the render method

Comment: Is this in a Customclass or not?

Comment: there are in the main class